# Excel 2013 - Miniature chart bug on "move to another sheet"?

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010, diagram, excel-2013

I wrote a VBA Macro a while back when I had Excel 2010 and it worked flawlessly. The result was a chart that at the end was moved to a dedicated new "diagram sheet" (so not a normal worksheet, but those ones who shows only graphic data).

Today I needed to use that macro again, I tried it on Excel 2013 and... The chart would be correctly moved to this other dedicated sheet, but it was miniaturized!

[image]

It was not possible to make it bigger and zooming in was of no help! 
I thought my Subroutine was flawed, but I had to try to move the chart manually to another sheet before... I got the same result! Closed Excel and reopened... Same result.

Now, does Excel 2013 have some stupid options set, so that those charts cannot be used, or is it a bug? ...And more important... How do I make this thing work?

Comment: Hard to tell what's up if you don't post the code.

Comment: It's not a code issue. I ran it on other pcs with Excel 2013 and it went just ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was generated by a failure of PRINTER DRIVERS (!) to cope with those "Chartsheets". I don't have a single clue of how this happens, but should you people have such problems, the only thing that will solve them is to change the printer also if you don't have to print anything.
Mine in this very case was Microsoft XPS Document Writer and I changed it to be a .pdf printer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the printer settings solved it for me in Excel 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I had connected to my local printer using an IP address. Every single Excel chart/graph which was saved as a separate sheet corrupted and it was impossible to change as CHART DESIGN was corrupt. As soon as I deleted the printer everything worked.

Thanks for spotting this bug. Microsoft had no idea how to fix this.